# Wildcard Host not working in MariaDB (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to add a user to my database using phpMyAdmin.

When I add the user the following way everything works fine:

UserName: user
Password: pass
Host: localhost

But when I create the same user and use "%" instead of localhost he cannot log in (even from localhost)

What can be the issue here?

(Update): This is the command that is generated:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0
```

(password has been removed by phpmyadmin)

Comment: Can you show the actual GRANT statement you are using?

Comment: Have you "flush privileges" ?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing; I cannot login on localhost unless I do a grant with 'user'@'localhost' explicitly. '%' seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any Anonymous Users.

From the [Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-connecting.html)

If you cannot figure out why you get Access denied, remove from the `user` table all entries that have `Host` values containing wildcards (entries that contain `%` or `_` characters). A very common error is to insert a new entry with `Host='%'` and `User='some_user'`, thinking that this enables you to specify localhost to connect from the same machine. The reason that this does not work is that the default privileges include an entry with `Host='localhost'` and `User=''`. Because that entry has a Host value `localhost` that is more specific than `%`, it is used in preference to the new entry when connecting from localhost! The correct procedure is to insert a second entry with `Host='localhost'` and `User='some_user'`, or to delete the entry with `Host='localhost'` and `User=''`. After deleting the entry, remember to issue a [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html) statement to reload the grant tables.